# Button does not fire the Click event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button, click

I have a `Button` inside a `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <ContentPresenter />
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>    
<Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" Click="Button_Click" />
```

But, if I specify a `Template`, this Button does not fire the `Click` event.
Why? How can I solve this problem?

The code-behind:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Click;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Click != null)
        Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: can you show me the code for the Button_Click in the code-behind file?

Comment: Have you set a break point to see that it is not firing? Or is it just returning null?

Comment: I've never really seen `Click` being used that way. Why don't you just put whatever code you want executed in your `Button_Click()` method? When you say `Click = BUtton_Click` then in essence you are attaching a handler to that event, you don't need to call `Click` again.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx

Comment: @TejasSharma you should learn about [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx)

Comment: I am aware of what a `UserControl` is. What does that have to do with routed events? And your link is for a winforms UserControl. Your question is about WPF.

Comment: @TejasSharma you're right, learn about WPF UserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button template is a simple ContentPresenter. In the code you give us, you put nothing in the button so it won't have any size. It will be impossible to click.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow">

<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <ContentPresenter />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" Click="Button_Click">
    <TextBlock Text="test" />
</Button>

</Window>
```

This code works and if you click on "test", the Button's Click event is correctly triggered. I did it in a window but it's the same in a UserControl.

If you are talking about your custom Click Event, it will be fired only if you attached an handler on it.

Comment: yes, if you want your button to be visible in your UI, and thus clickable !